# How to plot a 3D density map in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, mayavi, kernel-density

I have a large dataset of (x,y,z) protein positions and would like to plot areas of high occupancy as a heatmap. Ideally the output should look similiar to the volumetric visualisation below, but I'm not sure how to achieve this with matplotlib.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsNEL.jpg]

My initial idea was to display my positions as a 3D scatter plot and color their density via a KDE. I coded this up as follows with test data:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
z = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

xyz = np.vstack([x,y,z])
density = stats.gaussian_kde(xyz)(xyz) 

idx = density.argsort()
x, y, z, density = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx], density[idx]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=density)
plt.show()
```

This works well! However, my real data contains many thousands of data points and calculating the kde and the scatter plot becomes extremely slow.

A small sample of my real data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFT5V.png]

My research would suggest that a better option is to evaluate the gaussian kde on a grid. I’m just not sure how to this in 3D:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

nbins = 50

xy = np.vstack([x,y])
density = stats.gaussian_kde(xy) 

xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():nbins*1j, y.min():y.max():nbins*1j]
di = density(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, di.reshape(xi.shape))
plt.show()
```

Comment: For this application I think you might be better off using mayavi, which is more powerful for 3D visualization applications. Here's an [example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_chemistry.html#example-chemistry) from the docs that should get you started.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Thanks to mwaskon for suggesting the mayavi library.

I recreated the density scatter plot in mayavi as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from mayavi import mlab

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
x = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
y = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
z = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)

xyz = np.vstack([x,y,z])
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(xyz)
density = kde(xyz)

# Plot scatter with mayavi
figure = mlab.figure('DensityPlot')
pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, density, scale_mode='none', scale_factor=0.07)
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

[image]

Setting the scale_mode to 'none' prevents glyphs from being scaled in proportion to the density vector. In addition for large datasets, I disabled scene rendering and used a mask to reduce the number of points.

```
# Plot scatter with mayavi
figure = mlab.figure('DensityPlot')
figure.scene.disable_render = True

pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, density, scale_mode='none', scale_factor=0.07) 
mask = pts.glyph.mask_points
mask.maximum_number_of_points = x.size
mask.on_ratio = 1
pts.glyph.mask_input_points = True

figure.scene.disable_render = False 
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

Next, to evaluate the gaussian kde on a grid:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from mayavi import mlab

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
x = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
y = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)    
z = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)

xyz = np.vstack([x,y,z])
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(xyz)

# Evaluate kde on a grid
xmin, ymin, zmin = x.min(), y.min(), z.min()
xmax, ymax, zmax = x.max(), y.max(), z.max()
xi, yi, zi = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:30j, ymin:ymax:30j, zmin:zmax:30j]
coords = np.vstack([item.ravel() for item in [xi, yi, zi]]) 
density = kde(coords).reshape(xi.shape)

# Plot scatter with mayavi
figure = mlab.figure('DensityPlot')

grid = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(xi, yi, zi, density)
min = density.min()
max=density.max()
mlab.pipeline.volume(grid, vmin=min, vmax=min + .5*(max-min))

mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

[image]

As a final improvement I sped up the evaluation of kensity density function by calling the kde function in parallel.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from mayavi import mlab
import multiprocessing

def calc_kde(data):
    return kde(data.T)

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
x = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
y = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
z = 10*np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)

xyz = np.vstack([x,y,z])
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(xyz)

# Evaluate kde on a grid
xmin, ymin, zmin = x.min(), y.min(), z.min()
xmax, ymax, zmax = x.max(), y.max(), z.max()
xi, yi, zi = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:30j, ymin:ymax:30j, zmin:zmax:30j]
coords = np.vstack([item.ravel() for item in [xi, yi, zi]]) 

# Multiprocessing
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)
results = pool.map(calc_kde, np.array_split(coords.T, 2))
density = np.concatenate(results).reshape(xi.shape)

# Plot scatter with mayavi
figure = mlab.figure('DensityPlot')

grid = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(xi, yi, zi, density)
min = density.min()
max=density.max()
mlab.pipeline.volume(grid, vmin=min, vmax=min + .5*(max-min))

mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

Comment: This is great! Do you know how to plot this using a colormap that isn't jet?

Comment: @RovingRichard By using the keyword argument color= in the call to volume you can change it to be a single color. More advanced color maps can be done by creating a ColorTransferFunction as in the example at http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_pipeline_other_functions.html#volume

Comment: I can't get this to work with python 3.5.4 is there anyway to get this to work with matplotlib, seaborn, or bokeh?

Comment: Mayavi uses VTK C++ bindings under the hood and the later doesn't support Python 3 at present. I found matplotlib to be a poor solution for isosurfaces or anything complex in 3D. I'm sure it could be re-written using brokeh. Most of the JavaScript/brower-based graphing libraries have impressive rendering capabilities.

Comment: You have and example of this kind of plots when you consider only a slide of the plot? (For example  the plot with z=0)